# Terraform target aws_volume_attachment with only its corresponding aws_instance resource from a list

Tags: terraform

I am not able to target a single `aws_volume_attachment` with its corresponding `aws_instance` via `-target`. 
The problem is that the `aws_instance` is taken from a list by using `count.index`, which forces terraform to refresh all `aws_instance` resources from that list.

In my concrete case I am trying to manage a consul cluster with terraform. 
The goal is to be able to reinit a single `aws_instance` resource via the `-target` flag, so I can upgrade/change the whole cluster node by node without downtime.

I have the following tf code:

```
### IP suffixes
variable "subnet_cidr" { "10.10.0.0/16" }

// I want nodes with addresses 10.10.1.100, 10.10.1.101, 10.10.1.102
variable "consul_private_ips_suffix" {
  default = {
    "0" = "100"
    "1" = "101"
    "2" = "102"
  }
}

###########
# EBS
#
// Get existing data EBS via Name Tag
data "aws_ebs_volume" "consul-data" {
  count = "${length(keys(var.consul_private_ips_suffix))}"

  filter {
    name   = "volume-type"
    values = ["gp2"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.platform_type}.${var.platform_id}.consul.data.${count.index}"]
  }
}

#########
# EC2
#
resource "aws_instance" "consul" {
  count      = "${length(keys(var.consul_private_ips_suffix))}"

  ...

  private_ip = "${cidrhost(aws_subnet.private-b.cidr_block, lookup(var.consul_private_ips_suffix, count.index))}"
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "consul-data" {
  count       = "${length(keys(var.consul_private_ips_suffix))}"

  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = "${element(data.aws_ebs_volume.consul-data.*.id, count.index)}"
  instance_id = "${element(aws_instance.consul.*.id, count.index)}"
}
```

This works perfectly fine for initializing the cluster. 
Now I make a change in my `user_data` init script of the consul nodes and want to rollout node by node.
I run `terraform plan -target=aws_volume_attachment.consul_data[0]` to reinit node 0. 
This is when I run into the above mentioned problem, that terraform renders all `aws_instance` resources because of `instance_id = "${element(aws_instance.consul.*.id, count.index)}"`.

Is there a way to "force" tf to target a single `aws_volume_attachment` with only its corresponding `aws_instance` resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this sort of usage is not possible due to the fact that, as you've seen, an expression like `aws_instance.consul.*.id` creates a dependency on *all* the instances, before the `element` function is applied.

The `-target` option is not intended for routine use and is instead provided only for exceptional circumstances such as recovering carefully from an unintended change.

For this specific situation it may work better to use the `ignore_changes` lifecycle setting to prevent automatic replacement of the instances when `user_data` changes, like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "consul" {
  count      = "${length(keys(var.consul_private_ips_suffix))}"

  ...

  private_ip = "${cidrhost(aws_subnet.private-b.cidr_block, lookup(var.consul_private_ips_suffix, count.index))}"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["user_data"]
  }
}
```

With this set, Terraform will detect but ignore changes to the `user_data` attribute. You can then get the gradual replacement behavior you want by manually *tainting* the resources one at a time:

```
$ terraform taint aws_instance.consul[0]
```

On the next plan, Terraform will then see that this resource instance is tainted and produce a plan to replace it. This gives you direct control over when the resources are replaced, so you can therefore ensure that e.g. the `consul leave` step gets a chance to run first, or whatever other cleanup you need to do.

This workflow is recommended over `-target` because it makes the replacement step explicit. `-target` can be confusing in a collaborative environment because there is no evidence of its use, and thus no clear explanation of how the current state was reached. `taint`, on the other hand, explicitly marks your intention in the state where other team members can see it, and then replaces the resource via the normal plan/apply steps.